# Can I store fractions of seconds in R time variables?

Tags: r

```
> date_s
[1] "15  3 23 11 59 44.7"
> epochn=strptime(date_s,"%y %m %d %H %M %S")
> epochn
[1] "2015-03-23 11:59:44 CET"
> class(epochn)
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt" 
> as.numeric(epochn)
[1] 1427108384
```

It truncates fractions of seconds. Is there a class that can manage fractions of seconds and stuff like microseconds and nanoseconds or should I just make a separate numeric variables for that things?

Comment: Try %OS instead of %S.

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR:  Yes you can.

Longer answer: all this is documented.

1) You probably want `options("digits.secs"=6)` in your `~/.Rprofile` or files: It allows you to see sub-second data.

2) R can store to just above 1 microsecond in its native `POSIXct` type.  For higher precision you need to go to eg Boost Date_time and its optional nano-second support (which my RcppBDT can cover too).

3) For parsing, use `%OS` [1]

```
R> strptime("2015-12-27 10:11:12.34567", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
[1] "2015-12-27 10:11:12.34567 CST"
R>
```

4) For printing make sure you set enough digits:

```
R> now <- Sys.time()
R> print(now)
[1] "2015-12-27 16:24:42.198556 CST"
R> print(as.numeric(now))
[1] 1451255082
R> print(as.numeric(now), digits=16)
[1] 1451255082.198556
R>
```